# wpf image source: "format" binding (-> filename) with stringformat

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, string-formatting

i've got a INotifyPropertyChanged-abled class and thought it would be a good idea to use:

```
<Image Source="{Binding myfilename, StringFormat='FixedPath/{0}.png'}" />
```

so whenever i would change myfilename in source, i'd get the corresponding image in my wpf gui.

it compiles. but in the console i get the error that a TargetDefaultValueConverter converter failed to convert the value of myfilename. binding works ok. only the stringformat seems not to be applied.

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** this is somewhat conjecture

Based on some reading, that error occurs when the built-in converter fails to provide the correct type. So, what you're trying to do would be fine if the thing you're binding to expected a `string`. However, the `Source` property is actually of type `BitmapSource` - and for some reason, WPF is ok converting a raw `string` to a `BitmapSource` but because the target type isn't a `string` it is not ok running the built-in string formatter.

You could try making your own ValueConverter that does exactly this formatting.

Comment: You're correct about the type mismatch causing the error message. Additionally the StringFormat argument is only applied to non-string types so even if it was being assigned to a string property it would still not add the formatting. A custom converter is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's a rather bizarre limitation.